# Draw a cylinder using line_loop

Tags: c++, opengl

I am looking to draw a cylinder using GL_LINE_LOOP. I know there are more efficient ways to do this, but I am looking to do it in this specific way. Basically, I'm looking to replicate the image below using a nested for-loop. The steps I need to do are: find the coordinates of the yellow point, then the blue point, then the orange point, then the pink point. Once I have all of these points (each having their own x,y,z coordinates), I need to apply those points to LINE_LOOP vertices. once I applied these vertices, then I need to continue the parent loop onto the segment to the right until one section of the cylinder is done.

I understand conceptually how to do this but I don't know the algorithms behind finding delta's and theta's behind this problem. Any help is appreciated immensely.

You don't need to write the code line per line, pseudo code would do just fine.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to generate coordinates for a circle in 2D space?

Comment: isnt it something like, glBegin( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN );
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        for( int n = 0; n <= segments; ++n ) {
            float const t = 2*M_PI*(float)n/(float)segments
            glVertex2f(x + sin(t)*r, y + cos(t)*r);
        }
    glEnd();

Comment: Yes. Or you could use `GL_LINE_LOOP`, for example, and skip the initial `(x, y)`-point. Do you understand how to extend this to a cylinder in three dimensions?

Comment: I think thats part of my problem. but I did make something like this which can generate a circle if numSides is a large number glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
   float radius = 2.0;
   for (int i=0; i<numSides; i++)
   {
     float theta2 = i*radius*pi/numSides;
     float x = radius*cos(theta2);
     float y = radius*sin(theta2);
     glVertex3f(x, y, 0.0);
   }
  glEnd();

Comment: Why did you put `radius` into your calculation of `theta2` there? You should have `2` instead, so it becomes `2 * pi`. (Really, `2 * pi` is a better number than `pi` alone)

Comment: By adding another loop and filling in a `z`-value in your `glVertex3f`-calls, you should be able to create a cylinder-like object thats just multiple unconnected circles. Do you understand how to do this?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. My bad haha. Thanks for that tip! am I on the right track though? is the z value generated using cosine or theta?

Comment: You are on the right track. A cylinder is a circle that is linearly extruded, that is to say: for the circle you use `sin` and `cos`, but the other dimension, the `z` dimension, is linear, so you just use an increasing number. (Maybe `for (int z = 0; z < 10; ++z) ...`?)

Comment: oh yeah... duh. haha. Sorry I'm brand new to graphics. So how would I generate the lines passing through the circles?

Comment: If you take a step back and think about what your code is doing, you should be able to generate lines between adjacent points from different layers in your current cylinder. For each layer, the points with the same `i` will be directly above one another. Can you use this to generate the missing lines?